# Syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in for loop

Tags: xml, parsing, php

I am trying to parse some XML using PHP to get a status of my Farming Simulator 2013 Dedicated Server (no laughing please).  However, using a for loop to get the status of each possible player is not working.

My code is as follows.

```
<?php
    $info = simplexml_load_file('http://74.80.133.251:9090/feed/dedicated-server-stats.xml?code=049cb316c7d5137f7f285101d9657f13');
    $playerCount = $info->Slots['capacity'];
    echo $info->Slots['numUsed'];
    echo " slots out of ";
    echo $info->Slots['capacity'];
    echo " used.<br>";
    echo "<ol>";
    for ($1=0; $i<$playerCount; $i++)
    {
            echo "<li>";
            echo $info->Slots-Player[$i]['isUsed'];
            echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ol><br>";
?>
```

The source XML is located at `http://74.80.133.251:9090/feed/dedicated-server-stats.xml?code=049cb316c7d5137f7f285101d9657f13` and I know it is fairly simple to parse in C#, but I do not know PHP all that well.  Does anyone see something (probably simple) I am missing or some ideas to try?

Comment: This "bug" is caused by writing invalid php. Correct the syntax error at the line specified in the error message, and you pass programming 101. -1, /CV

Comment: Numbers are not allowed to declare as variables like this $1name, $1age and not even $1. it is wrong. Write a name for the variable not a number. a name can be $num. [see it](http://www.elcaro-guide.com/php-blog/variables-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors message is quite descriptive. A number was found instead of a variable

Fix the typo in the for loop. You have `$1` instead of `$i`

```
for ($1=0; $i<$playerCount; $i++)
```

should be

```
for ($i=0; $i<$playerCount; $i++) 
//    ^ 1 should actually be i
```

Comment: Well, now don't I feel stupid.  Thank you for spotting that simple typo.

Comment: what is `Slots-Player` ? You mean `Slots->Player` ?

Comment: Slots->Player should move to the next player slot on the server.  A little more research lead me to `foreach ($info->Slots->children() as $player)` which allows `echo "<li>" . $player['isUsed'] . "</li><br>";` and works.

Comment: Oh. your approach is even better.

Answer (score 0):

you have two mistakes i believe

```
for ($i=0; $i<$playerCount; $i++)
    {
            echo "<li>";
            echo $info->Slots->Player[$i]['isUsed'];
            echo "</li>";
    }
```

you had 1 instead of i, and you missed a > in one of your echos

Comment: Yep, all fixed now.   Please see my answer below with my working code (good enough for what I need).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, updated and working code as follows.

```
<?php
    $info = simplexml_load_file('http://74.80.133.251:9090/feed/dedicated-server-stats.xml?code=049cb316c7d5137f7f285101d9657f13');
    echo "$" . $info['money'] . "<br>";
    echo $info['mapName'] . "<br>";
    echo $info->Slots['numUsed'];
    echo " slots out of ";
    echo $info->Slots['capacity'];
    echo " used.<br>";
    echo "<ol>";
    foreach ($info->Slots->children() as $player)
    {
            echo "<li>" . $player['isUsed'] . "</li><br>";
    }
    echo "</ol><br><ol>";
    foreach ($info->Vehicles->children() as $vehicle)
    {
            echo "<li>" . $vehicle['name'] . "</li><br>";
    }
    echo "</ol><br>";
?>
```

Gives me the nice simple status page I care about.  Minus some formatting which I will deal with later.